# What is the usage of "se le ... " in this situation?

Tags: pronombres

Hello Spanish language community! I have always been troubled by some seemingly weird usage of "se le".

The scenario: the boss and the owner of a barber shop are trying to hire someone. They have just one candidate, but he demands too high a wage. So the owner and the boss are arguing about whether to hire him:

> The boss says: "Que no se le contrata y para eso soy la jefa" ...

> The owner says: "Y yo el dueño y se le contrata" ...

> The owner says: "Si hace falta, se le contrata solamente para un corte" ...

I looked up in the dictionary which tells me that "contratar" is mostly used as a transitive verb. So I try to determine first what the usage of "se" is in here:

1. A reflexive pronoun. I think it's unlikely, because usually it's "the owner/manager/boss 'contrata' a worker/employee". Ruled out.
2. A pronoun required by a pronominal verb. But the dictionary has no such an entry on "contratarse", which I think makes sense. Not this usage.
3. Passive, as in "Se venden las tartas en la calle"/"On the street cakes are being sold/someone is selling cakes on the street". If it is passive, then what is that "le" doing here? Wouldn't "se contrata **él** solamente para un corte" be more grammatical?
4. Impersonal se. I have been informed by many blogs and books that the impersonal "se" always requires a verb conjugated in 3rd person **singular** form, like: "Se entrevistó a muchas personas hoy"/"Many people were inverviewed today". Might this be the usage here?

And as for the "le", is it an instance of "leismo"? I mean "se lo contrata..." would sound correct to most Spanish speakers?

Any help is appreciated! I wonder which usage that "se" is, and whether "le" is "leismo" in action here.

Another related question: Why is it that in impersonal constructions, "se" almost acts like a grammatical subject? From Diccionario Oxford, it has an entry like this:

> se los acusa de subversión - they are accused of subversion

"they" is translated from "los". And if I am allowed to do something blasphemous to linguistics, "se" in its impersonal usage seems to act like a subject pronoun (in English, "one")! "One accused them of subversion" But "se" is an objective pronoun, be it a reflexive pronoun or indirect object. So now the questions is, what is the grammatical subject if you are forced to add one in impersonal constructions like(from Diccionario Oxford): "(What subject here?) se castigará a los culpables"/"those responsible will be punished"?

Thank you so much for any help!!!

P.S. there is a screenshot from the scene if it helps you understand the scenario:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb phrase:

- Se le contrata

is an impersonal verb phrase showing "leísmo" ("lo"/"la" should be used instead of "le" because, as you rightly point out, "contratar" is transitive).

As can be read [here](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/se-venden-casas-se-buscan-actores-frente-se-busca-los-culpables), this is a case of impersonal "se" because there is no subject (for a passive to exist, there needs to be a subject):

• Si el elemento nominal expresa persona y no va precedido de la preposición *a*, se emplea también la construcción de pasiva refleja:

```
     - Se buscan actores para la película.
     - Se contratarán nuevos trabajadores para el proyecto.
     - Se necesitan especialistas en informática.
```

• Si el elemento nominal expresa persona y va precedido de la preposición *a*, debe emplearse la construcción impersonal; por tanto, el verbo irá en singular aunque el elemento nominal sea plural:

```
     - Entre los gitanos se respeta mucho a los ancianos.
     - Se entrevistó a los candidatos para el puesto.
     - Se busca a quienes presenciaron lo ocurrido.
```

In the case at issue, we have:

- Se contrata **a**l peluquero / **a** la peluquera => Se **lo/la** ("le" with leísmo) contrata.

so it is the second case, that of an impersonal sentence.

Assuming it's a male employee they are hiring, the dialogue should be as follows:

> The boss says: "Que no se **lo** contrata y para eso soy la jefa" ...
>
> The owner says: "Y yo el dueño y se **lo** contrata" ...
>
> The owner says: "Si hace falta, se **lo** contrata solamente para un
> corte" ...

Comment: Why  not write in the first example, the full, accurate sentence?

Comment: "Se le contrata" can perfectly stand alone as a sentence. I chose to refer to the verb phrase (which as I said can work as a sentence in its own right) because it is shared by all three sentences in the dialogue.

Comment: Again: "("lo"/"la" should be used instead of "le" because, as you rightly point out, "contratar" is transitive)". is what **you say**.  So, why not include **your correction:** the one you give? Why not include the sentence: Se lo/la contrata. It is easier to understand with the example **written out**.

Comment: If I do that, the comment "showing 'leísmo'" will not apply, and I need to make that clear. I made an addition at the end.

Comment: Allow me to share something with you. If I provide a written explanation, I put the sentence that illustrates that after it. Sentences can be labeled. Cats are nice [plural]. A cat is a nice pet. [singular]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 3. Impersonal se. 'Contrata' is in the 3rd-person singular form. I think that 'se le contrata' is a dialectal form that express command, just do what I say, just do as I'm saying. That's it. I'm the owner so yes, 'he'll be hired'. It is being assumed as a fact and he/she won't take no for an answer.

> The boss says:
> "Que no se **le** contrata y para eso soy la jefa"
> ("No **lo(=a él)** vamos contratar, soy la jefa y se hace lo que yo digo")

> The owner says:
> "Y yo el dueño y se **le** contrata" ...
> (Y yo soy el dueño, así que sí será **(él)** contratado para el trabajo)

> The owner says:
> "Si hace falta, se **le** contrata solamente para un corte"
> ("Si hace falta, sí **lo(=a él)** vamos a contratar, pero solamente para eso" ...)

Yes, it acts like a subject pronoun, which is why in many cases it is not clear who the subject is. In some cases it is the repetition of the subject, which is redundant.

> **Se**(=ella, él, ellos, ustedes, alguien, nadie conocido) **los**(=a ellos) acusa(n) de subversión.

> **Él/ella/ellos/ellas/ustedes** acusa(n)  **a ellos** de subversión

> They are accused of subversion by **him/her/them/you**.

- Cuando **se** los topa en las ciudades(When **you** come across them in the cities)
- **Se** los iba a llevar con **ella** (**she** was going to take them with her)
- **Se** los volvió a llevar (**He** took them back)
- **A nadie** **se** le ocurrió cómo (**No one** can figure how)

In this case the subject may be the court, the justice, or the judge himself:

- **Se** condenará a los responsables por aquellos crímenes.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate explanation!